# Does whereEqualTo and whereArrayContains require an index?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Does this query require a Firestore index?

```
Firebase.firestore.collection("products")
.whereEqualTo("name", "sneakers")
.whereArrayContains("sports", "golf").get()
.addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        for (document in it.result) {
            val name = document.getString("name")
            Log.d(TAG,"$name")
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, it.exception?.message.toString())
    }
}
```

I cannot get any data, the rules are set in test mode and I get no message inside the Android Studio logcat. If add an orderBy call, I get the message in the logcat that says to create an index. That's weird.

Db:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot get any data"? If your query completes successfully with no documents in the result set, that just means there are no matching documents.  We can't see your data, so we don't know what this query will actually do for you.  Please edit the question to add more logging to explain more clearly what is happening that's different than what you expect.

Comment: It sounds like there are no matches for the query. Can you show a screenshot of the Firebase console of a document that you expect this query to maatch?

Comment: @DougStevenson "I cannot get any data" means that `Log.d(TAG,"$name")` doesn't produce any output, even if I have a product that satisfies the requirement. When I add an orderBy call, I get a message in the logcat, but without, I get no message and no print. Why is displaying a message when is an orderBy and not where there is not? It's because there is no need for an index?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please check my database. I'm sorry I didn't add it from the beginning.

Comment: Try this query on query builder in firebase console, then you can check the result

Comment: @AmanpreetKaur Sounds cool. I didn't even know we can do queries in the console. Thank you.

Comment: If there was a problem with indexes, you would get a clear error result from the query, not an empty result set.  An empty result set always indicates that there were no matches.